# Why the relationship between the tables not work? [FeathersJS - sequelize]

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, feathersjs, feathers-sequelize

I have:
 - the framework [Feathers](https://feathersjs.com) ^2.2.3
 - ORM [sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com) (feathers-sequelize ^2.3.2)
 - MySQL database
 - 2 tables (between them should work communication)

in file **category.model.js** describe the relationship:

```
category.associate = function (models) {
    models.category.belongsTo(models.category_translate, {
      foreignKey: 'id',
      targetKey: 'category_id',
      as: 'translate'
    });
  };
```

Now if you open **localhost:3030/category** then the result of this query is showed:

```
SELECT `id`, `icon`, `parent` FROM `category` AS `category` LIMIT 10;
```

Tried so **localhost:3030/category?$select[]=translate**, to access the fields from a linked table, but there was an error.

What I'm doing wrong?
How can I access data from another link table from the current model?

Thank You in advance for the answers!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a promotional channel, please don't edit those kind of links into your post.

Comment: Ok, no problem.